# Consumable inapp purchase issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, inappsettings

We are doing shopping-cart application.In this,for each inapp purchase we are giving 10 things.For this facility we implemented "Consumable inapp purchase".But itunes rejected our app due to consumable inapp purchse..So how can we implement "non consumable inapp purchase"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Apples website u can find whats wrong in ur App

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html

Hope it is help full to you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no difference in imolementing consumable and non consumable in-app purchase in iOS.

All the difference i see,is when you implement non consumable in-app, you have to check,if user has already purchase that item,and if he did,not show him "Buy" button anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For InApp purchase in ios 6 please refer following tutorial .

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial